# Dodgy sites hosted on azurewebsites.net

Tags: azure

This morning a user called me in a panic as she had all sorts of pop-ups and a woman telling her that her computer had been compromised,etc.

It turns out that it was all coming from a website hosted on azurewebsites.net as follows:

https://mndcr3s3sd5ghm.azurewebsites.net/mntr4ce8i/
https://mndcr3s3sd5ghm.azurewebsites.net/mntr4ce8i/txW088Inse08880it0yCED008MUY008/index.html
https://mndcr3s3sd5ghm.azurewebsites.net/mntr4ce8i/txW088Inse08880it0yCED008MUY008/index.html#

How do I go about reporting this site to Microsoft?

Comment: Google "azure report abuse". https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/knowledge-center/how-do-i-report-a-security-incident-or-abuse/

Answer (score 0):

You can report abuse for MS services here - https://msrc.microsoft.com/report/abuse